# Kubuntu Dolphin saving to remote does not trigger inotify on remote

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, samba, sftp, dolphin

I added a remote network connection (sftp) to Dolphin. When I open a file from the remote location, edit and save it, this "save" action does not trigger an event which is watchable with inotify. I don't understand why, since the file changed on the remote.

inotify is watching the file in a process on that remote machine, not on the one using Dolphin. If I `touch` the file on that remote machine, inotify reports this properly.

Why is this happening? I have another text editor on Windows which supports sftp, and whenever I save a file with it, it does trigger an inotify event on the remote machine.

Same problem with samba connections.

Comment: Is it possible that dolphin is backing up the file (or deleting it) and then replacing it with a new copy? You inotify will be against the file descriptor, so if dolphin is creating a new file then you wont get notified, but you should get notified of the first deletion. Try watching the directory, that should tell you if dolphin is creating new files.

Comment: @TuxInvader No, inotify is not reporting a deletion. If I later touch the edited file on the remote, it still triggers a notification, so it is the same file.